# How are floating point representations (say single precision for instance) able to represent more numbers than what a 32 bit memory allows?

Tags: binary, floating-point, numbers

I am trying to understand the floating point system. Can the floating-point system represent all the real numbers within the range of (10^38) accurately? If so, then how is it possible? Because technically, we still have only 32 bit memory available (for single precision) and we can at most represent upto just 2^32 in it.

Answer (score 4):

> How are floating point representations (say single precision for instance) able to represent more numbers than what a 32 bit memory allows?

They're not able to, and they don't.

There are still only 2^32 possible values. The difference is how those values map to numbers. An unsigned integer starts at 0, and uses every value to represent every integer after 0, until the available values run out.

Floating point numbers break this 1-to-1 mapping. At the extremes, more and more numbers are skipped.

You can use this [online calculator](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to play around with 32 bit floats.

Consider the largest representable integer by 32 bit float (0x7f7ffffe), which represents `340282346638528859811704183484516925440`. The next smallest integer is `340282326356119256160033759537265639424`, which is `2^104` less. There are no 32 bit floating point representations between these two values.

Comment: Thank you. I get it now. But, how do scientists and engineers get away with these inaccuracies? This seems huge.

Comment: @Viper: The results of real-world measurements are often several orders of magnitude less accurate than the difference between two adjacent `float` values. They learn from the very beginning how to deal with that.

Comment: Double precision lets you represent your distance from the center of the sun with about 0.03 millimetre resolution. Or the time since 1AD within a tenth of a millisecond.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'm sure there are some real world magnitudes that need to be more precise than that, but I'm certainly they would occur for a demographic that already has a very solid understanding of high precision, high performance computing.

Comment: @Viper: for greater precision, there are [extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) and [quadruple precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) formats (though they are machine-dependent), and [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). Extended precision is usually used for intermediate calculations to deal with overflow or underflow of double-precision numbers, rather than because greater precision is needed in the results.

Comment: ... Also, read about [alternatives to floating-points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Alternatives_to_floating-point_numbers) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is it can't, and it doesn't. A range of 10<sup>38</sup> for a 32 bit float corresponds to an 8 bit exponent (`⌈log2(1038)⌉ = 127`, which takes 7 bits, plus one for the sign bit), leaving just 24 bits for the significand, one of which is another sign bit. Since the most significant bit of a floating point number is always 1, it's left off of common floating point formats. Still, with only 24 bits of precision, floating point numbers are less precise than integer types *that are greater than 2<sup>24</sup>-1*.

One of the advantages of floating point numbers over finite-precision (i.e. not bignum) integer types and fixed number types is that the latter two waste space by always include leading zeros. Floating point numbers, in contrast, essentially shift the digits over, allowing digits to be used for fractional digits (they still store trailing zeros, which is also wasteful).

To understand this, it can be easier to start with decimal equivalents. Imagine a 10 digit processor. It can work with 10-digit integers, or 10-digit floating point numbers (8 digits for the significand, and 2 for the exponent); signs are magically free (and ignored here). The number 10 is stored as `0000000010`. All those leading zeroes are there, just taking up precision. Floating point numbers are basically scientific notation (but with limited precision), so 10 is `1.0000000e01` (the `.` and `e` are implicit, and not actually part of the stored representation, but are shown here for clarity). Note all those leading zeros are gone, and we have all those fractional digits. There are fewer digits overall for the significand (8 instead of 10), so for numbers > 10<sup>8</sup>, you get [round-off error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) and lose the least significant digits. The integer `123456789`, when converted to floating point, would be stored as `1.2345678e08` (if truncated) or `1.2345679e08` (if rounded to nearest).

Now switch back to binary. An 8-bit 0b1 (assuming 2s complement, 1s complement, sign-magnitude or similar) is stored as `0000 0001`. 32 bit has even more "waste". A floating point binary number, in contrast, doesn't need to include any of those leading 0s, or even the 1. The stored representation of the number 0b1.01011 (in decimal, 1.34375) can thus start with the .01011, using the precision on the fractional bits rather than leading 0s.

There are other representation details, such as exactly how sign is handled, and how exponents are stored, but not only are they beyond the scope of this Q&A, they also can vary from platform to platform, so shouldn't be used in programming (unless your project is to create a floating point library on a specific platform, and even then it's much preferable to use the native operations rather than twiddle bits).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A single precision floating point number takes 32 bits. 1 bit is used for the sign, 8 bit for a binary exponent, and 23 bits for the mantissa.

With the exponent 2^0, we get 2^23 values 1.0 ≤ x < 2. With the exponent 2^1, we get 2^23 values 2.0 ≤ x < 4. With the exponent 2^100 we get 2^23 values 2^100 ≤ x < 2^101.